# Zap flagging failure for "Found csrf token parameters in URL."

Tags: javascript, nginx, url, zap

I am using the nginx web server, and has the form page which have the CSRF token(anticsrf) as a hidden field in the form. But since it is used in the form i guess it forms the query string and appears in the URL. Now the Zap is detecting it as the vunerability.

alert :  CSRF information in URL parameters.
name :  CSRF information in URL parameters.
riskcode :  3
confidence :  2
riskdesc :  High (Medium)
desc :

Scans to ensure that URL's formed to make HTTP requests do not contain csrf tokens.

Instances:

```
 uri :  https://10.197.127.174/?anticsrf
 method :  GET
 param :  anticsrf
 attack :  
 evidence :  
 uri :  https://10.197.127.174/?anticsrf&body_input&cmds&endpoints=%2Fapi%2Fmo%2Fsys.json&endpoints=restconf%2Fdata%2FCisco-NX-OS-device%3ASystem%2F&rollback_type=stop-on-error
 method :  GET
 param :  anticsrf
 attack :  
 evidence :
```

Why is ZAP detetcing it as a failure? since the tokens are anyway needed in the form.

Also what is the way to fix it?

Comment: The parameter should be POSTed not sent via GET query parameter.

Comment: If you set it in a query parameter it's leaked in situations where the user navigates away from your site (via referer), it's leaked in their history, it's leaked on shared systems, etc.

Comment: Currently our form is     <form name="input" id="input" action="/" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="hidden" name="anticsrf" value=""> like this that is no method, so you are asking to mention the method as POST here to avoid the vulnerability?  also we are sending only in form , not as parameter, still u feel it as leaked?

Comment: You can easily test it yourself. Goto the form in a browser, open dev tools, goto the networking tab. When you complete the form and submit it are all the details leaked via query params?

Comment: I am not seeing any leak of query parameters in get method in network tabRequest URL: https://10.126.67.48/index.html
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 10.126.67.48:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin.  I am not adding that as query parameter. Does Zap tool generates the different URL based on the form fields? and then flag the token for csrf in URL?

Comment: No the examples you quoted would have actually been encountered in the app and passively scanned by ZAP.

Comment: You mean this example?                                                                                           uri :  https://10.197.127.174/?anticsrf&body_input&cmds&endpoints=%2Fapi%2Fmo%2Fsys.json&endpoints=restconf%2Fdata%2FCisco-NX-OS-device%3ASystem%2F&rollback_type=stop-on-error
I am not seeing the query params leak in network tab? so what is the other way the app could have encountered it? also there is no way of get request for it, so how zap is getting that uri? also how does zap does passive scan and get url?

Comment: I mean my question is from app, what they can send is only Request URL: https://ip/api/mo/sys.json here there is no query string, we only send this. but in zap the vulnerable urls all habe query string like https://10.197.127.174/?anticsrf how is this uri with query string coming?